# complex variable inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $B$ and $C$ be nonegative real numbers and $A$ a complex number. Suppose that 
$$
0\leq B-2Re(\overline{\lambda}A) + |\lambda|^2 C \ \forall \ \lambda \in \mathbb{C}
$$
 Conclude that $|A|^2 \leq BC $ (hint: if $C = 0$, show that $A = 0$. If $C \neq 0$, then choose $\lambda = \frac{A}{C} $

So i can do the first step of letting $C = 0$, but i don't even know what to conclude from this...... I am pretty much lost with it all

Comment: If the inequality holds for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$, then it holds in particular for $\lambda$ of the form $t\cdot A$, with $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How do i show it?

Comment: If you plug $\lambda = t\cdot A$ into the inequality, a little manipulation gives you a quadratic polynomial (with real coefficients) on the right hand side. Use what you know about real quadratic polynomials.